# Trouble with UIViewControllers when pushing to UINavigationController - iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

My iOS 7.1 App has a strange Bug. See Pic below. It's happen when i try to pushing the Alarm-ViewController on UITableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath Event. Any Ideas how to fix that ?

[image]

Code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Alarm *alarm = _settings.sharedSettings[indexPath.row];

    AlarmViewController *alarmViewController = [[AlarmViewController alloc] initWithAlarm:alarm];
    alarmViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TITLE",  nil);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:alarmViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You are pushing a view controller with an UIPickerView and it shows up transparent? is that it? Maybe you can explain the problem better.

Comment: Yes and No. Okay let me try to explain better. I have a TableViewController from there i try to push to an other ViewController (AlarmViewController). The AlarmViewController is splitted (Top: DatePicker, Bottom: SettingsTableView) like the Standard iOS7 AlarmClock-App in the Edit-Mode. Okay, now AlarmViewController will pushing but when pushing (from the TableViewController to AlarmViewController) overlaps the TableViewController with AlarmViewController during animation duration. The Overlaps appears only on the Top-Part of the AlarmViewController but in BOTH directions. It's clearer? Thanks

Comment: @TiagoLira: Okay, i could solve me Problem. You give the right hint. You are right, i just needed to set background-color=white to the View of AlarmViewController and there is no transparency and overlapping anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Solution. 
Just set the Background-Color of the UIView.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//add other Controls to view

self.view = view;
```